# What is the "practical purpose" of Gaussian surfaces?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Without having the concept of a Gaussian surface, we know that charges induce fields in  proportion to quantity. Now to take a common example, when describing flux through a (physical) surface it is often suggested that we draw a Gaussian cylinder perpendicular to the surface and use it to count flux. Now my question is, if the surface is of infinitesimal size (encloses one charge) then the diameter of the cylinder is also infinitesimal (encloses one line of flux). What predictive or explanatory ability have we gained by drawing it?

Similar questions, I think, can be asked about gaussian spheres and cubes. If we know that particles create fields and induce flux, why do we need to be able to draw an imaginary surface to count them?

Comment: I haven't quite understood exactly what you are asking...

Comment: I mean, basically occam's razor says we make ideas only if we expect them to expand our ability to explain or predict phenomena. What phenomena are made possible/easier to predict /explain/calculate with g-surfaces?

Comment: Well, you can calculate very easily the electric field configurations of many scenarios using those Gaussian surfaces. Also is very useful to calculate contour conditions of vector fields.

Comment: This question needs some clarification.  Please revise.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the usage of Gaussian surfaces is based on Gauss's law, which is mathematically equivalent to Coulomb's law. So you are right in saying that fundamentally, using Gaussian surface doesn't add deeper insight.

However, what is interesting about Gaussian surfaces is that they are only useful when some kind of symmetry is present. In your example where you try to draw a cylinder around a single charge, there is no symmetry at work. Gaussian cylinders are helpful in two simple scenarios: 1) Infinite sheet of charge (translational symmetry) 2) Line of charge (radial symmetry around the line) Gaussian spheres, on the other hand, are useful when you have spherical symmetry (which fits the case of a single charge!) So Gaussian surfaces are really just tools to facilitate calculations and elucidate the presence of symmetry.

Comment: In other words the purpose is just to identify symmetry?

Note to mods - I seem to have made 2 upvotes with 1 click

Comment: Joe, you can check [your "votes" tab](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/5302/joe-stavitsky?tab=votes) (link is Joe Stavitsky specific and won't work for anyone else), but likely you just happened to vote at about the same time as your computer registered the addition of a vote from another user.

Comment: @JoeStavitsky Well it is not really to identify symmetry. I think it is more like the usefulness of Gaussian surfaces reflect certain symmetries. And since symmetries are nice, Gaussian surfaces are pretty nice :)